# Translation function calls must NOT contain PHP variables

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the Theme-check plugin, and it's helped me cleanup my theme quite a bit. One of the recommended changes I make says the following: 'Possible variable $options found in translation function in theme-options.php. Translation function calls must NOT contain PHP variables.'

What I have is
`<input id='critter_theme_options[phonenumber]' class='regular-text' type='text' name='critter_theme_options[phonenumber]' value='<?php esc_attr_e( $options['phonenumber'] ); ?>' />`

What is the correct way of saying `esc_attr_e( $options['phonenumber'] );`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/)  is explained pretty well what to do to make it work.

EDIT (from comment): So in your case

```
printf( "
  <input id='critter_theme_options[phonenumber]' class='regular-text' type='text' name='critter_theme_options[phonenumber]' value='%s' />",
  esc_attr( $options['phonenumber'] ) );
```

Comment: I read through that, I'm just not sure how to grab the value without $options

Comment: printf( "<input id='critter_theme_options[phonenumber]' class='regular-text' type='text' name='critter_theme_options[phonenumber]' value='%s' />",
esc_attr( $options['phonenumber'] )
);

Comment: Thank you Mainz007, will this still be called the same as I would before?

Comment: As far as I know yes :) Maybe you need the function esc_attr__() instead

Comment: ...ah wait, I'm now getting the error 'Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context'